# Does this translation make sense?

Tags: metaphors, poetry

I'm trying to translate a piece of my poem which is in Persian into English. I've so far come up with this:

> And what you see is a bewildering reflection of shadows, leaving the light lost on its way.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, by the way. Saeed, that is lovely. You must understand that there is enormous freedom for language in poetry, so there is a _lot_ of room for different interpretations. If you are saying _the shadows have obscured the light_, that  is clear. One must ask here, though, of your phrase, "Are shadows reflected? Is not only light reflected? What does it mean, 'reflection of shadows'? Is it literal or figurative? Do I "see" with my mind's eye?" All these re valid for poetry, but in written language, one might strongly question _reflection of shadows_".

Comment: @Susan: Thank you Susan. I'm trying to portray a state of mind in which doubts (referred to as shadows) are so overwhelmingly dominant that they leave no room for certainty (referred to as the light). The "reflection of shadows" is used here as a metaphor for the fact that doubts usually bring further doubts.

Comment: Then you have translated it very well!

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find our sister-site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: “English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation.